# How to link gwt-super-dev-mode with a web application launched by play!1.2.7

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework, gwt2, gwt-super-dev-mode

I've got a problem with my web application, running on Firefox and built with Play!1.2.7, GWT2.6 on Windows 7. I'm using Eclipse Kepler as IDE.

First of all, in production mode, the application works. The problem is to make it work in dev mode, which enables debug configuration. The plugin GWT for Firefox that enables dev mode is not supported by recent versions of firefox, therefore, we use the "Super Dev Mode" plugin instead.

If I get it right, we have to launch the application first, then the super dev mode plugin.

First, to launch the application, in a command line, at the root of the application, we do a

```
            play start
```

Then, to launch the dev mode, in Eclipse, we configure a run configuration for a java application:

```
            Project: MyWebApp
            Main class: com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer
            Program arguments: -src app/ App -workDir C:\Users\user\workspace\MyWebApp\
            classpath, user entries:
            gwt-dev-2.6.0.jar - \MyWebApp\lib
            gwt-user-2.6.0.jar - \MyWebApp\lib
            gwt-codeserver-2.6.0.jar - \MyWebApp\lib
            app - - \MyWebApp\
            src - C:\play-1.2.7\modules\gwt2-1.8\
            play-1.2.7 - C:\
```

When I run this java application, I have the following error:

```
            workDir: C:\Users\user\workspace\MyWebApp
            deleting: C:\Users\user\workspace\MyWebApp\App\compile-1
            binding: user.agent=safari
            binding: compiler.useSourceMaps=true
            binding: locale=en
            Compiling module App
               Validating units:
                  Ignored 81 units with compilation errors in first pass.
            Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
               Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter'
                  Rebinding com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter
                     Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.SimpleBeanEditorDriverGenerator'/>
                        [WARN] Detected warnings related to 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver'.   Are validation-api-<version>.jar and validation-api-<version>-sources.jar on the classpath?
                        Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.
                        [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule
               Compiling 1 permutation
                  Compiling permutation 0...
                  Source Maps Enabled
               Compile of permutations succeeded
            Linking into C:\Users\user\workspace\MyWebApp\App\compile-1\war\myModule; Writing extras to C:\Users\user\workspace\MyWebApp\App\compile-1\extras\myModule
               Invoking Linker Export CompilationResult symbol maps
                  [ERROR] Failed to link
            com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
                at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.StandardLinkerContext.invokeLinkForOnePermutation(StandardLinkerContext.java:376)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.finishPermutation(Link.java:480)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.doSimulatedShardingLink(Link.java:442)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.link(Link.java:175)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:200)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:115)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:58)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeModules(CodeServer.java:120)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:95)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:71)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:49)
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
                at com.google.gwt.thirdparty.debugging.sourcemap.SourceMapGeneratorV3.mergeMapSection(SourceMapGeneratorV3.java:243)
                at com.google.gwt.core.linker.SymbolMapsLinker.link(SymbolMapsLinker.java:308)
                at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.StandardLinkerContext.invokeLinkForOnePermutation(StandardLinkerContext.java:373)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.finishPermutation(Link.java:480)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.doSimulatedShardingLink(Link.java:442)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.link(Link.java:175)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:200)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:115)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.ModuleState.<init>(ModuleState.java:58)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeModules(CodeServer.java:120)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:95)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:71)
                at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:49)
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                ... 13 more
```

Do you have any idea to solve the problem ?
Thank you very much!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I added the latest JSON library to my classpath and it fixed the problem.  For Maven users, adding the following to your pom.xml will prevent the error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Be advised I'm not sure which version is the best to use.  I was using GWT 2.6.1

PS: This is a similar to another question / response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989851/358006